# Optimal storage of checkboxes / multi-select in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, checkbox, relational

Situation: Users will select up to ~10 options via checkboxes / mutliselect. There may be as few as 1 or up to all 10 options selected. I am looking for the best method to store the data in a mysql database such that:

(1) Queries to pull this data are fast. I will not need to update, do complex joins, etc. on the data, I just need to pull the data.
(2) Minimal storage space is needed
(3) This is extensible in that new options may be added to the checkboxes in the future
(4) It is not tedious to write the code for it (PHP)

Options:

1. Serialize the data and store in a single column / row
2. Store each option selected as a a separate row under a single column of "option name"
3. Store a single row for each submission. Have a column for each option with a bit to mark if that option is selected

Any thoughts on what is best?

Answer (score 0):

Use **normalization**.

Make child table for storing options separately with foreign key constraints with main table.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I will make a good EER Diagram, and normalize the DB, beside that will take a look to the InnoDB and MyISAM engines to see which onr you should use in each table, beside that if you are worried for your query you can still using tools to see how can you improve your query, but if you put everything in one table, one row, you wont even make use of INDEX or and your DB will be overload with a lot of repeated information